# How to decompress the tar file into specific folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, tar

I have tried with the command

```
if (-not (Get-Command Expand-7Zip -ErrorAction Ignore)) {
>>   Install-Package -Scope CurrentUser -Force 7Zip4PowerShell > $null
>> }
PS C:\Users\noufal p> Expand-7Zip C:\Amazon\abc123d-setup.tar C:\awsUsers\%USERNAME%\Downloads
```

But getting error => The path 'C:\Amazon\abc123d-setup.tar' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.

Comment: So, does it exist? What does `Test-Path C:\Amazon\abc123d-setup.tar` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the error message is wrong - i think its actually complaining about the output location? Couple of things jump out me:

`c:\awsUsers\` - is this correct/does it exist?

`%USERNAME%` - probably should be `$env:USERNAME` (have you tried hard-coding a value and see if that works?)

Based on the above assumptions, you could try:

```
Expand-7Zip C:\Amazon\abc123d-setup.tar "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Downloads"
```

Or just cut out the middle-man and use 7z.exe directly:

```
start-process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList @("x -ttar C:\path\to\a\archive.tar -oc:\path\to\output")
```